# Unscramble image using python

Tags: python

I have a function that scrambles images like this:
Put all even columns on the left and all odd columns on the right.
Repeat nx times.
Do the same for rows ny times.

By using the following code:

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import imread, imsave

def imshuffle(im, nx=0, ny=0):
    for i in range(nx):
       im = concatenate((im[:,0::2], im[:,1::2]), axis=1)
    for i in range(ny):
       im = concatenate((im[0::2,:], im[1::2,:]), axis=0)
   return im

 im1 = imread('circles.png')
 im2 = imread('mountain.jpg')

 imsave('s_circles.png', imshuffle(im1, 7,7))
 imsave('s_mountain.jpg', imshuffle(im2, 8,9))
```

Now how can I unscramble image back to original?

[example of scrambled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SnQv.jpg)

Comment: Suppose that you have a list of numbers that you "scramble" by putting all the even ones to the left and the odd ones to the right. Take a list like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` for example. Do what you say 3 times. What do you think happens?

Comment: the array will become 1 4 2 5 3 6         
                      1 2 3 4 5 6 ->  1 3 5 2 4 6 -> 1 5 4 3 2 6 -> 1 4 2 5 3 6

Comment: @ChatterOne, I don't think your example is equivalent. In your example, you look at the value of the rows/numbers, in the question they look at the index. Except if you meant sorting them by index, then it is indeed equivalent but no strange behaviour happens then, at least not for what I can see.

Comment: @debsim it doesn't matter if you look at the value or the index, you can consider them the columns number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 if you want

Comment: @ARCHANAYADAV `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` will become `2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5`, `4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3`, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` (i.e. back to start)

Comment: @debsim Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I get what you mean now but it's actually what I meant: you take the odd index and the even index and move the value that is there. See my example just above

Comment: but applying function imshuffle to an array it  returns  1 4 2 5 3 6

Comment: @ChatterOne are you suggesting to rotate array for n/2 times will give an original array

Comment: @ARCHANAYADAV It depends on how many times you applied your scramble. If you have a list of 10 numbers and rotated only once, then you need 4 more times to get back the original list. So you have to either remember how many times you did the rotation, or always apply the same number of times.

Comment: As this is 2d array, so I should rotate r/2-1 times the rows and c/2-1 times row and to unscramble I should rotate it for only once.   That's right?

Comment: @ARCHANAYADAV I didn't try it but that looks reasonable

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution to your problem but I think this will help you further.
Try to solve this problem by first solving it for a simple list of numbers. So, try to find a function `inverse()` that does the opposite of your `scramble()` function. Like this:

```
original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
permutated_list = scramble(original)
# permutated_list = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
inverse(permutated_list) # = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Once you have this function, decoding a sequence that was scrambled multiple times is easy. Just apply `inverse()` as many times as `scramble` was applied. Like this:

```
sequence = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(3):
    sequence = scramble(sequence) 
# sequence = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
for i in range(3):
    sequence = inverse(sequence)
# sequence = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So now you can decode a sequence, using this inversion in 2D (image) is not hard, you just have to pay attention to the order of operations. Like this:

```
scrambled_image = scramble_rows(scramble_columns(original_image))
original_image = unscramble_columns(unscramble_rows(scrambled_image))
```

This approach is very useful for more complex problems. Try to simplify the actual problem as much as possible (eg. 2D sequence of pixels -> 1D sequence of numbers and n scrambles -> 1 scramble). Once this simplified problem is solved make it a bit more complicated towards the direction of the actual problem (eg. solve it for n scrambles) and keep doing this until the actual problem is solved.

I hope this can help you further.